# Do dependent sources work in two directions?

Tags: circuit-analysis

For example if i have a voltage controlled voltage source and between the output terminals of the voltage controlled voltage source is an independent voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxWzmk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Will the voltage source now work reserved? Putting 0.5V over R1? Or is there a very high current trough the wires of the right part due to the very small unmodelled resistor of the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, VCVS as well as other voltage/current controlled sources are only one-way.

You're just creating a short-circuit between two voltage sources. One (The controlled one) want to set Vin*K, the other (v2) wants to set 1V.

An ideal transformer model (not to be confused with the ferromagnetic transformer model, which includes ALSO but not only an ideal transformer model) is maybe what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

VCVS will not work in reverse, it's one way only. It will not source any sort of signal to its input terminals.

You have put two voltage sources in series (VCVS1 and V2) with no current limiting resistance. If you try to simulate this, it will refuse, with an error message along the lines of 'loop of zero impedance, singular matrix'.